# Karma grunt, where do the output go?

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner

Karma is new to me. This is my configuration. I can run $grunt karma but it produces nothing? There should be a test in that location because running Jasmine works and I get an error from my test. Why dont i get any feedback from Karma.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'css/common.css' : 'sass/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
                src:  'js/dev/**/*.js',
                dest: 'js/build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: ['js/dev/**/*.js'],
            options: {
                globals: {
                    jQuery: true,
                    console: true,
                    module: true
                }
            }   
        },
        jasmine : {
            src : 'js/test/**/*.js',
        },
        karma: {
          unit: {
            options: {
              files: ['js/test/**/*.js']
            }
          }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'sass', 'jshint', 'jasmine'] );
    //Dev task(s)
    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['watch'] );
    //Karma
    grunt.registerTask('karma', ['karma'] );

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have enough configuration information in your gruntfile for karma to do anything.  For example, you don't specify what browser(s) to use.

Try changing your karma option section to something like this:

```
karma: {
  unit: {
    options: {
      files: ['js/test/**/*.js'],
      frameworks: ['jasmine'],
      browsers: ['Chrome']
    }
  }
}
```

*N.B: this assumes you have Chrome on your system.  If you don't, you can easily install the [karma launcher](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/browsers.html) for your browser (Firefox, Safari, IE) via npm.  You'll also need the [karma-jasmine module](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/plugins.html), if not installed.*

There are several good references you can use as a launching point for working with grunt and karma.  Here are three to get you started:

1. [karma project example](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/v0.8.5/test/client/karma.conf.js) - useful reference while reading the karma configuration [docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html)
2. [cobbdb/grunt-karma-example](https://github.com/cobbdb/grunt-karma-example/blob/master/gruntfile.js) - puts all karma configuration into the gruntfile
3. [hollandben/grunt-karma-example](https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-karma-example/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) - specifies config is in `karma.conf.js`